# Maven: The following artifacts could not be resolved. Where to place the friend's .m2 folder on my Mac?

Tags: macos, maven

My friend and I are working on a project using Maven on Windows. 
I want to run the same project on Mac. I do not know where to place the .m2 folder that I copied from Windows on Mac.

I put the .m2 into `/Users/.m2`. When I run the `mvn clean install` from the folder with a pom file I get:

```
Could not resolve dependencies for project ...
```

Comment: First copying the cache is a bad idea...apart from that the cache on Mac is under the appropriate user like `/Users/USERNAME/.m2/` ...Just transfer the project (I hope you are working with a version control system like Git/SVN etc.) and just try to build it on the Mac on plain command line `mvn clean package`..The downloads will be done automatically...

Comment: Dear @khmarbaise, it worked. I placed in the /Users before, which was wrong. Thanks! Shall you put this as answer, so I can acknowledge it?

Comment: Added as answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First copying the cache is a bad idea...apart from that the cache on Mac is under the appropriate user like `/Users/USERNAME/.m2/` ...Just transfer the project (I hope you are working with a version control system like Git/SVN etc.) and just try to build it on the Mac on plain command line `mvn clean package`. The downloads will be done automatically.